# Enforce error type with Result monad comprehension

Tags: kotlin, monads

I have a `Result<V, E>` type where `V` is the value type and `E` is the error type.

I am trying to implement monad comprehension such that I can do this:

```
val result: Result<Int, String> = binding {
    val value = someMethodReturningResult().bind()
    val value2 = someOtherMethodReturningResult().bind()

    value + value2
}
```

I tried to implement the `bind()` method to throw an exception containing the error if the result is a failure, or else return the value.

Consequently, the `binding` function contains a try/catch which returns a `Result` with either the thrown error or the returned value.

Since exceptions cannot contain generic types, I have to cast the error to `Any` before throwing, and then cast it back in the catch block. While this works, it is not typesafe. 
Someone might add a call to `someThirdMethodReturningResult().bind()`, which has another type for the error, and this should not be allowed.

Is there any way to enforce that each call to `bind()` has the same type for the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can imagine *maybe* doing something like

```
class BindingContext<E> {
  fun <T> Result<T, E>.bind(): T
}
fun <T, E> binding(block: BindingContext<E>.() -> T): Result<T, E>
```

...in which the `BindingContext` is the `this`, and the `bind` method is an extension function on `Result` that only exists within `BindingContext`.